# Object initializer syntax in Array.prototype.map()

Tags: javascript

```js
let a = [{num:'1'},{num:'2'}];
let b = ['1','2'];
let c = b.map(i=>{num:i});

console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```

I expected variable c to be identical to a, which doesn't happen. Why is the Object initializer syntax not allowed as I'm using it?

Comment: Your object initializer is being treated like a code block. Use parentheses for it to be evaluated as an expression. `({num:i})`

Comment: what 4castle said. Furthermore, it's not a problem with map but in general with arrow functions.

Comment: As a perhaps irrelevant side note. The example initializes a new array with incrementing numbers. The same can be done with `let c = Array.from({length:2},(o,i)=>({num:i+1}));` (Same goes for parentheses around the arrow function though.)  For 2 entries it doesn't matter, but for larger quantities it makes life easier. Likely it was just an example, but thought I'd mention it just in case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the classic Javascript one: the contents of your arrow function are being treated as a block, not as a function literal, with `num` as a label, not as an object key. You need to wrap the literal in brackets `()` to make it work:

```
let a = [{num:'1'},{num:'2'}];
let b = ['1','2'];
let c = b.map(i=>({num:i}));

console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```